# Function Looks Poisson-Like: But What's the Parameter $\lambda$?

Tags: power-series, approximation, statistical-inference

(On pause)

I have

$$f\left(x\right)=-x\left( x\sqrt{4-x^2}-4\arccos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \right)\arccos\left(\frac{x^2+d^2-1}{2dx}\right)$$

which looks a bit like the continuous version of Poisson distribution in $k=x$ with parameter $\lambda=d$ (or a function of $d$) such that I can write

$$
f\left(x\right)\approx\frac{\lambda^x\left(d\right)  e^{-\lambda \left( d \right)}}{x!}
$$

where $\lambda\left(d\right)$ is some function I need to find (and $x!$ is the gamma function since $x$ is continuous). I've tried the usual methods, but can't get very far. Is there a way of finding $\lambda\left(d\right)$, perhaps just for $d\approx2$ (which I can use if necessary).

See this screenshot, containing a plot of $f(x)$ for $d=2$
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how $f$ looks like a Poisson Distribution?  [Doing a quick plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-x%28x*%5Csqrt%28x%5E2%2B4%29+-+4*arccos%28x%2F2%29%29*arccos%28%28x%5E2%2B2%5E2-1%29%2F%282*2*x%29%29++from+x%3D0.5+to+x%3D1.5), $f(x)$ looks like it is only positive and real for $1\le x < 1.3$ (about).

Comment: plot the function again, notice the -x at the beginning

Comment: Try using the FindFit function in Mathematica to get a bearing on what $\lambda$ could be.